# Chrome thinks my site "looks fake" after code-level redirect to other country TLD

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, redirect, tld

I've implemented a code level redirect when someone hits the wrong TLD. i.e. `store1.example.com` -> `store1.example.ca`

I do a db query based on the subdomain hit to see which country that store is registered too and redirect to the correct TLD.

Chrome says "The site you tried to visit looks fake. Attackers sometimes mimic sites by making small, hard-to-see changes to the URL"

Anyone dealt with this before?

Comment: Use server-side redirecting instead.

Comment: @ChrisG Ideally that's exactly what I'd do but the infra is in a state where I have to do the redirect at the code level

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow.   Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.